# Laravel - Distinguish session by user_ID

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have a project where a logged in user can fill in some data. This data will then be stored in a session called "Main_settings". The way I do that is by doing this in my controller:

```
private $predefinedArray = ['user_id', 'city', 'postal_code', 'street_name',
                            'house_number', 'store_name', 'store_tel',
                            'store_hoo', 'vat_number'];

public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach($this->predefinedArray as $value) {
        $request->session()->put('main_settings.' . $value, $request->input($value));
    }

   return redirect('themes');
}
```

I call the session variables by doing this in my view:

`{{ session('main_settings.store_name') }}`

If the user returns, His information will still be there, That's not the issue. The problem is, if John Doe logs in and starts filling in the form and then logs out. And Jane Doe logs in, The information that John Doe filled in will be displayed, While Jane Doe didn't even fill anything in yet.

Somehow I need to distinguish a session by a user ID so I can call the session of the logged in User in the view. How can I accomplish this?

The user_id is being sent WITH the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered clearing `main_settings` when a user logs out?

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. The session is unique. How is it possible? Can you provide more info? 'Cause seems like you missed something

Comment: @haakym I'm not quite certain, In laravel, I thought that happened automatically, If not, How can I accomplish that? I know the code needed is `$request->session()->flush();` but that can only be done if it is a request?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot This is all the information I have of this problem. The only thing I can give you extra is the HTML form, I don't think that is needed here.

Comment: Ah, ok I got it :) You've been set request->session instead of session(). So there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, if John Doe logs in and starts filling in
>   the form and then logs out. And Jane Doe logs in, The information that
>   John Doe filled in will be displayed, While Jane Doe didn't even fill
>   anything in yet.

This is happening because you are not forgetting those values when John Doe logs out. If you would like to remove the inserted values when John Doe logs out, have a look at this.

**Controller.php**

```
private $predefinedArray = [
    'user_id', 'city', 'postal_code',
    'street_name', 'house_number', 'store_name',
    'store_tel', 'store_hoo', 'vat_number'
];

public function logout()
{
    session()->forget('main_settings');

    auth()->logout();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

This should help you achieve the result.

---

If, for any reason, you want to retain the values in the session, you can do the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach($this->predefinedArray as $value) {
        session()->put(auth()->id().'.main_settings.' . $value, $request->$value);
    }

   return redirect('themes');
}
```

By adding `auth()->id()`, you have persisted in the session, the user's id and the settings that he inserted while filling the form. This in turn will help the logged in user, because they then don't have to fill all the details again.

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.